# Swift Firebase data format

Tags: json, swift, firebase

when I did asked firebase the following.

```
    print("\(WarSerArray[CompanyData.companyName]!.allValues)")
    print("keys\(WarSerArray[CompanyData.companyName]!.allKeys)")
```

it printed out this information.

```
[{
    PhonNumber = 7607588500;
    address = "2378 Primrose Ave. Vista, CA. 92083";
    currentStoreArray = Headquarters;
    email = "james@opportunitysoftware.com";
    faxNumber = "";
    key = "-KLSM8y0BDfs6B1jtsA5";
    name = "Service Center 1";
}]
keys[-KLSM8y0BDfs6B1jtsA5]
[{
    PhonNumber = 7607588500;
    address = "2378 Primrose Ave. Vista, CA. 92083";
    currentStoreArray = Headquarters;
    email = "james@opportunitysoftware.com";
    faxNumber = "";
    key = "-KLSM8zu6AFKa7V0beCh";
    name = "Warehouse 1";
}]
keys[-KLSM8zu6AFKa7V0beCh]
```

how do I get name?

Comment: what is `WarSerArray`? what is `CompanyData`? Please always keep in mind to provide a well detailed question so we have the proper resources to help you.

Comment: pls add more details per comments above if you'd like the community to help, thanks

Comment: WarSerArray = (snapshot.value)! as! NSDictionarystruct WareServiceStruct {
    var name = String()
    var address = String()
    var currentStoreArray = String()
    var phoneNumber = String()
    var faxNumber = String()
    var email = String()
    var key = String()
    
}
var WarehouseData = WareServiceStruct()

Comment: var CompanyData = CompanyDataStruct()

Answer (score 0):

```
var CompanyData = CompanyDataStruct()  

struct CompanyDataStruct {

    var key = ""
    var webpage:String! = ""
    var OwnerName:String! = ""
    var address:String! = ""
    var managerPNumber:String = ""
    var dueOnOrder = 0.0
    var email:String! = ""
    var fax:String! = ""
    var itemsOrderHistory:String! = ""
    var companyName:String! = ""
    var money = 0.0
    var notes:String! = ""
    var tax = 0.0
    var pNumber:String = ""
    var ManagerContact = ""
    var opw:String! = ""
    var mpw:String! = ""
    var OwedToCompany = 0.0
    var OwedString:String! = ""
    var taxID:String! = ""
    var reSalesID:String! = ""
    var BoxCount = 0
    var secondTicketID:String! = ""
    var secondTicketNumber = 0
    var useSecondTicketID = false
    var printerSettings = ""
    var quoteDays = 0
    var fulfillmentPrinter = false
    var fulfillmentEmail = false
    var printBill = false
    var emailBill = false
    var system = false
    var printReceipt = false
    var emailReceipt = false
    var theFulFillEmail = ""
    var logoName = ""
    var delivery = false
    var ac1 = ""
    var ac2 = ""
    var ac3 = ""
    var storeID = ""
    var warehouse = ""
    var serviceCenter = ""
    var currentStore = ""
    var StoreCount = 0
    var WareHouseCount = 0
    var ServiceCenterCount = 0
    var MoneySymbol = ""
    var refundLevel = 0
    var shareBarcode = true
    var LoGoImage = DefaultImage

}

var WarehouseData2 = WareServiceStruct()

struct WareServiceStruct {
    var name = String()
    var address = String()
    var currentStoreArray = String()
    var phoneNumber = String()
    var faxNumber = String()
    var email = String()
    var key = String()

}

let WareSerRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Owner").child("CompanyName").child("WareServ")
let WareSerRefName = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Owner").child("CompanyName").child("WareServ").child("name")
let WareSerRefAddress = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Owner").child("CompanyName").child("WareServ").child("address")
let WarSerRefCurrentStore = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Owner").child("CompanyName").child("WareServ").child("CurrentStore")
let WareSerRefPhone = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Owner").child("CompanyName").child("WareServ").child("PhoneNumber")
let WareSerRefFax = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Owner").child("CompanyName").child("WareServ").child("faxNumber")
let WareSerRefEmail = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Owner").child("CompanyName").child("WareServ").child("email")
let WareSerRefKey = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Owner").child("CompanyName").child("WareServ").child("key")

    func WarehouseFirebaseSetter(sedner: WareServiceStruct) {

    let key = WareSerRef.childByAutoId().key

    WarehouseData2 = sedner

    WarehouseData2.key = key
    let WareToAdd = FBWarhouseData
    let childUpdates = ["/Warehouse /\(CompanyData.companyName)/\(key)":WareToAdd]
    WareSerRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
}



var FBWarhouseData = ["address" : WarehouseData2.address,"currentStoreArray" : WarehouseData2.currentStoreArray,"email" : WarehouseData2.email,"faxNumber" : WarehouseData2.faxNumber,"PhonNumber" : WarehouseData2.phoneNumber,"name" : WarehouseData2.name,"key" : WarehouseData2.key] as NSDictionary
```

Comment: Let me know if you need more.